# C - Monte Carlo Integration - Randoms not random and count not counting?

Tags: c, random, integration

Heads up, I'm a bit of a C newbie :P

I'm trying to figure out why my program isn't running as intended.

First, it's supposed return an x and y value within the range 0.0 to 10.0, which it does, but shouldn't randoms reset after each run? I'm getting the same X and Y values every time I run the program.

Second, my loop doesn't seem to be doing anything. The count isn't increasing at all and I have no clue why - I'm assuming this is fixed, I should start seeing some correct results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void throwDart(double *x, double *y)
{
    double min = 0.0, max = 10.0;

    *x = (max - min) * ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) + min; //don't nec. need min - example format
    *y = (max - min) * ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) + min; //^same
}

double Fun(double x)
{
    return ((0.3*x*x) - (0.2*x) - 5); //estimate value of definite integral using this function
}

int main()
{
    double x, y, P; //(x,y) is location, P is number of darts that hit below the curve/total thrown
    int N, e; //N is number of darts, e is area under curve
    int c = 0; //initialize count of darts that hit below the curve

    throwDart(&x, &y);

    printf("How many darts would you like to throw?\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (y <= Fun(x))        
        c++;    
    }

    P = c/N;
    e = 100.00 * P;

    //most of the following prints just to see what is and isn't working
    printf("X is %lf\n", x);
    printf("Y is %lf\n", y);
    printf("N is %d\n", N);
    printf("c is %d\n", c);
    printf("P is %d\n", P);
    printf("Area under the curve is %d\n", e);

    system("Pause");

}
```

Comment: To get other random values you have to set the seed of the pseodo-random generator - using `srand`. `time(NULL)` is somewhat popular seed. As to the loop you never change value of `y`, since you throw dart once at the beginning of the progam.

Comment: So I just srand (time(NULL)); in throwDart and make sure to include time.h? I tested it real quick and it did have an effect so X and Y are changing, but for whatever reason Y is changing more drastically than X? I also just noticed that Y is always just going to be that same value. In the srand case, since Y was less than X, it was just counting N times. You're right, it doesn't make sense, just don't know what would replace it.

Comment: If you're doing serious Monte Carlo work--integration or simulation--`rand()` is totally inadequate, even after you fix your seeding and other bugs. Get a good external PRNG library. Then call it inside the loop (not the seeding function--call that outside).

Comment: @Link2999 - you should invoke `srand` in `main` - not every time the random is invoked. Otherwise you pretty much defeat its purpose - with each new seed, a new series of random numbers is generated from the start. If you do `srand(1)` -> 3x`rand()` -> `srand(1)`  -> 3x`rand()` you're going to get the same three values again.

Comment: @lared Thanks! Got it working for the most part, now I'm just have to fix some of my doubles and ints, but it seems to be good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm used by `random` is *pseudo*-random. It depends on a value called `seed` - if you can set it to a different value each time the program is started, you will get other series of random numbers. By default `seed` is set to `1`, so the series won't change. Somewhat popular way is to use the number of seconds since the epoch as seed:

`srand(time(NULL));`

`srand` changes seed of the pseudo-random generator to the given value, `time` returns time in seconds since the epoch, so it consistently uses different series with each invocation of the program. `srand` should only be invoked once, preferably somewhere at the start of `main` (to make sure the seed is set properly for the first invocation of `rand`).

As to your loop question - you never change the value of `x` or `y` there. You should invoke `throwDart` with each iteration to get new values of `x` and `y`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    throwDart(&x, &y);
    if (y <= Fun(x))        
    c++;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to seed the random number generator. You can do this by calling `sranddev()` at the top of your `main()`.

Secondly, both `x` and `y` stay the same value each iteration of the loop, so by the end of the program `c` will either be 10 or 0. If you seed your random number generator you will see this happen.

Comment: Is there any difference between sranddev() and srand()?

Comment: `sranddev()` seeds using /dev/random so you don't need to pass it a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Random number generators aren't really random, they're what's called pseudorandom, or 'fake' random, since a computer can't just come up with a value, you need to give it a seed value that gets plunked into an algorithm to return back a seemingly random number, and that normally gets the job done

With C and C++ the random number generator needs an explicit seed value, if you don't give it one it will just keep picking the same one every time, thus the issue with you getting the same numbers for x and y every time.

So you need to give it a different seed every time the program is run, and the easiest way to do this is using the time.h file

```
#import <time.h>
```

And as was said farther up, seed the random number generator, each time you call it

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

time in this case is the number of seconds since the clock was started some 20 years ago, so you will continue to get the same number if you call the rand function more than once a second, which will happen in a for loop, so I would recommend doing this instead

```
srand(time(NULL) + i);
```

inside the loop, so the seed changes each time rand is called, and you always get different numbers

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `srand` more than once. What would you do it for? If you do it in each iteration of the loop you're going to end up with 2 different values returned by `rand` (assuming the code's going to finish in one second)

Comment: Oh, forgive me, I haven't done C/C++ in a while, setting a seed only needs to happen once, the value changes consecutively after each rand call. I was thinking about if you had two separate rand objects, you'd need to seed them differently if they were being created at the same time, but that's not the case here.